# How do implement a main menu?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I have to create a project where students are able to play 4 interactive simple games.
When they open the flash file there is the menu with 4 buttons. Each button opens the correspondent game.

I dont understand it. Shall I have a 4 buttons on frame 1 and when first button is clicked then go to frame 2?

Or shall I create a 5 different projects(menu, game 1, game n). if so then how can I connect them?

How can I implement this? Any tips is appreciated.

Comment: do you have the 4 interactive games or not yet ? it's better to use `actionscript` it you have the games in each swf you can just use html menu with url that lead to each page that have swf game, no need to create a menu swf

Comment: TY for comment. Yes I have the games. Though somebody else made them. Each game is in one flash project.  The thing is that we are going to publish this project in CD and give it to students. It is important that they do not have access to the swf files and share them on TPB. any tips?

Comment: create folder that have all games and hide it, in html just provide the correct path it will show it, only someone who have some computer knowlege will know that the games folder is hidden, so the cd will show only html pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mgraph thank you for your response. 
I have actually managed to solve this problem using AIR in CS6.

Regarding the publish:
Export the flash project as an AIR application.

Regarding the menu: Put the menu on frame 1 and game1 on frame 2. 
Make sure game1 is a movieClip.

Thank you.